# how to connect emulator to vscode?

Tags: flutter

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:63918/KikEmMbQf4g=/

how can i get rid of this error,what can i do get rid of this error. i don't know what to do. In first, my emulator is not working in android  studio then i reinstall the emulator, but now it show me this error   =>[Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:63918/KikEmMbQf4g=/]<= in DEBUG CONSOLE in vscode.

Comment: can u run `flutter doctor -v` & edit your question with these information?